# Enable DOM/XML on Centos 6.3

Tags: php, centos, xml

After some research from our team and trial and errors, we we're not able to make '--disable-dom' dissapear from the phpinfo.

I've tried to reinstall php-xml but I got the following message:

```
Package php-xml-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

The server is running on CentOS release 6.3 (Final)

Here's the info under 'dom' section of phpinfo:

```
DOM/XML               enabled
DOM/XML API Version   20031129
libxml Version        2.7.6
HTML Support          enabled
XPath Support         enabled
XPointer Support      enabled
Schema Support        enabled
RelaxNG Support       enabled
```

Anything else we should try in order to have the --disable-dom removed from the php configuration?

Thanks.

[EDIT]

Is There an easy way to recompile php on CentOS6 ?

Comment: We finally found the problem. It was Chmod permission for the cache folder. It couldn't write, so we chmod 777. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to? There is absolutely no need for what you're trying to do.

The reason that `--disable-dom` appears in the `phpinfo()` is that on Red Hat, PHP and its modules are generally built separately; PHP actually gets built three times (or maybe it's four) during the RPM build process to account for each SAPI. Once the resulting binaries are installed on your system, though, there is no functional difference.